python how to check if a user email is added in gcp project's iam
# Replace with your own service account key file path
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = "/home/myuser/credentials_gcp.json"
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
import os
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE

# Define the required scopes
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform']

# Authenticate using the service account
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)

# Build the IAM service
service = build('iam', 'v1', credentials=credentials)

# List all users in the IAM policy
def list_iam_users():
    users = []
    request = service.projects().serviceAccounts().list(name='projects/my-project')
    while request is not None:
        response = request.execute()
        for account in response.get('accounts', []):
            users.append(account['email'])
        request = service.projects().serviceAccounts().list_next(previous_request=request, previous_response=response)
    return users

print(list_iam_users())


Above code works to list service account but i want to check if user exist or not. "service.users()" does not exist.
Is there any other fun or library to know if a user exist in iam?

able to list all user through code posted on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69478763/gcp-user-list-using-python.

Firstly, do not use a service account key file, it's a bad practice. Then, Google Cloud do not have any users management. Google Cloud create service accounts, and it's the only accounts managed by Google Cloud. You can also have the IAM service that manage permission and role, and you can grant account (user or service) on resources (project, folder, or sub level resources). If you want to access the user account, you have to use the Google Workspace API. The user accounts live there

There are 3 types of client libraries for Google Cloud:

API that you're using (for IAM);
Cloud Client (for Cloud Resource Manager -- see code below)
gRPC

See Client libraries explained
In this case, you're likely better placed using Google's Cloud Resource Manager service. Specifically the getIamPolicy method which returns Policy types. Policy binding members are prefixed by type (e.g. user:) see members
You can append --log-http to any gcloud command to see the underlying service/methods being used and, in this case:
gcloud projects get-iam-policy ${PROJECT}

Uses:
gcloud projects get-iam-policy ${PROJECT} --log-http
=======================
==== request start ====
uri: https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{PROJECT}:getIamPolicy?alt=json
method: POST
...

NOTE: gcloud continues to use old API versions (v1) but the client library is at v3 and this is the version used in the code below.
Using Pypi google-cloud-resource-manager and Python client for Resource Manager
main.py:
import os

from google.cloud import resourcemanager_v3
from google.iam.v1 import iam_policy_pb2


PROJECT = os.getenv("PROJECT")
EMAIL = os.getenv("EMAIL")

def main():
    client = resourcemanager_v3.ProjectsClient()

    request = iam_policy_pb2.GetIamPolicyRequest(
        resource=f"projects/{PROJECT}",
    )
    response = client.get_iam_policy(request=request)

    for binding in response.bindings:
        # Policy binding members are prefixed by type (e.g. 'user:')
        if f"user:{EMAIL}" in binding.members:
            print("found")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Google does a good job in documenting its client libraries: get_iam_policy includes the  example used in the above.
NOTE The code returns explicit bindings to the Project and does not include implicit (inherited) bindings.
